# Symbolic coordinates with explicit labels are in wrong order

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to use a pgfplots `scatter` plot to create a matrix representation. So far everything worked, I'm using a table as input and colour the scatter points by meta data. My `x` and `y` column should be with equal distance between labels, so I used symbolic coordinates.
Now I figured I need to skip some data, since it is not valid, however this produces wrong plots.

In order to skip the data I tried to replace the invalid values with `nan` or simply deleted the corresponding rows from the datatable. The results are below. The closest I've come is shown under point **3.**, which corresponds to the main problem, however, for the sake of completeness and since I would take any solution I also showed my alternative approach in **2.**.

1. The **original**, complete table including invalid data can be found in the MWE below, I do not have enough reputation to post three images.
2. Invalid data **replaced with `nan`**
   [image: Data, in which all invalid values have been replaced with <code>nan</code> in the .csv file]
   To point out the difference, all data in the `y=0.5` row except `x=3.2` is invalid. It has in this representation been replaced with a minimum value and looks like it has a value of 2 (yellow) (also compare below, 3.)
3. Invalid rows **delete** from the dataset
   [image: Image where the invalid datapoints are removed from the input]
   Here I removed the lines from the input, and the graphical output is correct. However, now my symbolic coordinates *labels* get mixed up. 
   If I remove the `yticklabels={0.5, 1.0,2.0,3.0}`, the coordinates are labels correctly. I also get the correct result, if I write `yticklabels={1.0,2.0,3.0,0.5}`, i.e. in the wrong order. So, somehow I guess something about the mapping goes wrong.

Does anyone know, why this happens? Is it a bug, or is there an (obvious?) solution?

My (sorta) MWE for all three cases:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[
    optimize=true,
    mode=convert with system call
    ]

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{data-complete.csv}
x y val
1.6 0.5 2.6672
1.6 1   2.8316
1.6 2   3.1649
1.6 3   3.6555
2   0.5 2.093
2   1   1.9881
2   2   2.2279
2   3   3.1646
2.4 0.5 2.1954
2.4 1   1.9281
2.4 2   2.6658
2.4 3   3.8962
2.8 0.5 2.4146
2.8 1   2.5022
2.8 2   3.1728
2.8 3   4.1442
3.2 0.5 2.8957
3.2 1   3.1781
3.2 2   4.2107
3.2 3   6.6232
3.6 0.5 4.7931
3.6 1   4.2339
3.6 2   6.0685
3.6 3   7.5076
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{data-cut.csv}
x y val
1.6 1   2.8316
1.6 2   3.1649
1.6 3   3.6555
2   1   1.9881
2   2   2.2279
2   3   3.1646
2.4 1   1.9281
2.4 2   2.6658
2.4 3   3.8962
2.8 1   2.5022
2.8 2   3.1728
2.8 3   4.1442
3.2 0.5 2.8957
3.2 1   3.1781
3.2 2   4.2107
3.2 3   6.6232
3.6 1   4.2339
3.6 2   6.0685
3.6 3   7.5076
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{data-nan.csv}
x y val
1.6 0.5 nan
1.6 1   2.8316
1.6 2   3.1649
1.6 3   3.6555
2   0.5 nan
2   1   1.9881
2   2   2.2279
2   3   3.1646
2.4 0.5 nan
2.4 1   1.9281
2.4 2   2.6658
2.4 3   3.8962
2.8 0.5 nan
2.8 1   2.5022
2.8 2   3.1728
2.8 3   4.1442
3.2 0.5 2.8957
3.2 1   3.1781
3.2 2   4.2107
3.2 3   6.6232
3.6 0.5 nan
3.6 1   4.2339
3.6 2   6.0685
3.6 3   7.5076
\end{filecontents*}

\tikzsetnextfilename{complete}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{
        colormap={yellowred}{rgb255(0cm)=(255,255,0); rgb255(1cm)=(255,0,0)}
        }

    \begin{axis}[
        %width=10cm, height=10cm,
        ytick=data, xtick=data,
        xlabel={x},
        ylabel={y},
        enlargelimits={abs=0.6cm},
        symbolic y coords={0.5,1,2,3}, yticklabels={0.5,1.0,2.0,3.0},
        symbolic x coords={1.6,2,2.4,2.8,3.2,3.6}, xticklabels={1.6, 2.0, 2.4, 2.8, 3.2, 3.6},
        x=1cm, y=1cm,
        point meta min=2, point meta max=8,
        unbounded coords=jump,
        colorbar, colormap name=yellowred,
        colorbar style={
            ylabel={Value, -},
            ylabel near ticks,
            yticklabel style={
                /pgf/number format/precision=0,
                /pgf/number format/fixed,
                /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
                },
            },
        ]

        \addplot[
            only marks,
            mark size=0.42cm, mark=square*,
            scatter, scatter src=explicit, 
            scatter/use mapped color={
                draw=mapped color, 
                fill=mapped color
            },
            ] 
            table[x=x, y=y, meta=val] {data-complete.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikzsetnextfilename{cut}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{
        colormap={yellowred}{rgb255(0cm)=(255,255,0); rgb255(1cm)=(255,0,0)}
        }

    \begin{axis}[
        %width=10cm, height=10cm,
        ytick=data, xtick=data,
        xlabel={x},
        ylabel={y},
        enlargelimits={abs=0.6cm},
        symbolic y coords={0.5,1,2,3}, yticklabels={0.5,1.0,2.0,3.0},
        symbolic x coords={1.6,2,2.4,2.8,3.2,3.6}, xticklabels={1.6, 2.0, 2.4, 2.8, 3.2, 3.6},
        x=1cm, y=1cm,
        point meta min=2, point meta max=8,
        unbounded coords=jump,
        colorbar, colormap name=yellowred,
        colorbar style={
            ylabel={Value, -},
            ylabel near ticks,
            yticklabel style={
                /pgf/number format/precision=0,
                /pgf/number format/fixed,
                /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
                },
            },
        ]

        \addplot[
            only marks,
            mark size=0.42cm, mark=square*,
            scatter, scatter src=explicit, 
            scatter/use mapped color={
                draw=mapped color, 
                fill=mapped color
            },
            ] 
            table[x=x, y=y, meta=val] {data-cut.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikzsetnextfilename{nan}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{
        colormap={yellowred}{rgb255(0cm)=(255,255,0); rgb255(1cm)=(255,0,0)}
        }

    \begin{axis}[
        %width=10cm, height=10cm,
        ytick=data, xtick=data,
        xlabel={x},
        ylabel={y},
        enlargelimits={abs=0.6cm},
        symbolic y coords={0.5,1,2,3}, yticklabels={0.5,1.0,2.0,3.0},
        symbolic x coords={1.6,2,2.4,2.8,3.2,3.6}, xticklabels={1.6, 2.0, 2.4, 2.8, 3.2, 3.6},
        x=1cm, y=1cm,
        point meta min=2, point meta max=8,
        unbounded coords=jump,
        colorbar, colormap name=yellowred,
        colorbar style={
            ylabel={Value, -},
            ylabel near ticks,
            yticklabel style={
                /pgf/number format/precision=0,
                /pgf/number format/fixed,
                /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
                },
            },
        ]

        \addplot[
            only marks,
            mark size=0.42cm, mark=square*,
            scatter, scatter src=explicit, 
            scatter/use mapped color={
                draw=mapped color, 
                fill=mapped color
            },
            ] 
            table[x=x, y=y, meta=val] {data-nan.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, your question is really about the `data-cut.csv` case, and its interaction with `yticklabels`. I think it would be better to limit your MWE to that case.

Comment: Yes and no. The `data-cut.csv` is the closest I've come to an usable solution, however I also wanted to show my alternative approach.
Still, considering my title.. you are right. I'll add an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will only discuss the `data-cut.csv` case in this answer.

The relevant options you use are:

```
ytick=data,
symbolic y coords={0.5,1,2,3},
yticklabels={0.5,1.0,2.0,3.0}
```

Note that the `yticklabels` values do not correspond to the `symbolic y coords` values, but to the `ytick` ones, which are automatically defined since you used `data`. This means that the coordinate of the first element will be labelled `0.5`, not the coordinate of the element with *symbolic coordinate* `0.5`.

An easy fix is to properly define `ytick`:

```
ytick={0.5,1,2,3}
```

[image: render]

Answer (score 1):

For the `data-nan.csv` case:

You can use a workaround to map the lowest values (the `nan` in this case) to white, by using a colormap with three colors:

```
colormap={yellowred}{rgb255(0cm)=(255,255,255); rgb255(0.1cm)=(255,255,0); rgb255(100cm)=(255,0,0)}
```

The distances on the map are picked in order to get the transition to yellow as soon as possible, in order for the lowest real values to show the right color. Output is the same as in @tonioelgringo 's answer.

Note that in the question two values are below 2, they will be mapped to the start of the colormap (white in this case). This can be solved by changing those values to, e.g., 2.01 or by changing `point meta min` to, e.g., 1.9.

Comment: Also, you can filter them with a point filter: `filter point/.code={\edef\tmpa{\thisrow{val}}\edef\nan{nan}\ifx\nan\tmpa\pgfkeys{/data point/x=nan}\else\fi}` or so.

Comment: I had thought about using white, but in my actual picture I also have gridlines, which would look weird. The filter would have helped, but there I'm not practised enough in tex/latex/pgf coding.